# Custom labels are not translated

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel, translation

I created a lightning web component(LWC) with **custom labels**.
And I also set translation with these labels. (My default lang is Japanese, and translation is English).

But I found these labels is always showing itself in **English**, even though lang and locale is set to ja and ja_JP correctly.

This behavior is same on **LightningApp** and **Visualforce** with lightningOut.

How can I get the correctly tranlated labels?

Here is sample code and meta.

*force-app/main/default/lwc/labelTest/labelTest.js*

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import translate from '@salesforce/label/c.translate';
import lang from '@salesforce/i18n/lang';
import locale from '@salesforce/i18n/locale';

export default class LabelTest extends LightningElement {
  @track translate = translate;
  @track info = {
    lang,
    locale,
  }
}
```

*force-app/main/default/labels/CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <labels>
        <fullName>translate</fullName>
        <language>ja</language>
        <protected>true</protected>
        <shortDescription>翻訳</shortDescription>
        <value>翻訳する</value>
    </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

*force-app/main/default/translations/en_US.translation-meta.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customLabels>
        <label>Translate</label>
        <name>translate</name>
    </customLabels>
...
</Translations>
```

*force-app/main/default/translations/ja.translation-meta.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customLabels>
        <label><!-- 翻訳する --></label>
        <name>translate</name>
    </customLabels>
...
</Translations>
```

This gives me below.
[image]

Please help me!

Comment: I did notice you have a trailing comma after "locale" but it's inconsequential when I run the code (stylistically incorrect though).
I tried with default org as EN and JP with my own user settings in both contexts.  It showed the JP / EN translations appropriately.  This may be something germane to your org as I cannot repro.

Comment: Thank you @jmdohn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try and error after this post.
I solved this somewhat.

While in my question, jp translation is commented out as default.
However I changed it to the same as the custom label value (looks like below), I got correct label.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customLabels>
        <label>翻訳する</label>
        <name>translate</name>
    </customLabels>
...
</Translations>
```

But I think this behavior is different from other salesforce services.